# Jest unit test - mock value of async function within async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs

In my React project, I'm unit testing an async function that calls another async function.

```
//SomeComponent.js
getAllJobs = async () => {
    var allJobStatuses = new Array();
    for(var endpointForRegion in this.props.regionalEndpointsMap) {
        let jobStatusesForRegion = await getJobStatuses(endpoint);
        allJobStatuses = allJobStatuses.concat(jobStatusesForRegion);
....
    }
    return allJobStatuses;
}

getJobStatuses = async (endpoint) => {
   const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
   ......
   return await response.json();
}
```

```
//SomeComponentTest.js
describe('<SomeComponent />', () => {
    ....
    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {regionalEndpointsMap: {
             'region1': 'region1ep',
             'region2': 'region2ep'
        }};
        wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent {...props} />);
    });
    it('should get jobs for all regions', async () => {
        var startTime = new Date();
        let mockdata = {[
            {
            jobId: 'id',
            }
        ]};

        jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'getJobStatuses').mockResolvedValue(data);
        let allJobs = wrapper.instance.getAllJobs();
        let expectedData = [
            {jobId:'id'},
            {jobId:'id'}
        ];
        expect(allJobs).toEqual(expectedData);
}
```

Though every time this is tested, the result ends up just being an empty Promise {} instead of the expectedData.
I've tried many implementations I've found online for mocking the result of the async 'getJobStatuses' function with no luck (showing the implementation I used from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736193/jest-test-fails-for-async-function-that-calls-another-async-function). What would be the correct way to mock a result for this function, for the purposes of testing the function calling it (getAllJobs)

Answer (score 0):

Since `getAllJobs` is `async` it will return a promise. Did you mean to `await` the promise here?

```js
let allJobs = await wrapper.instance.getAllJobs();
```

Comment: Anything that will allow it to return with the expected value (sorry still new to react and green with using async/await in JS in general). When I add `await` to the wrapper call of getAllJobs, I receive a `ReferenceError: getJobStatuses is not defined` error oddly